# Transition on axis with appended text

Tags: d3.js

How do I apply transition on x-axis in the following code:

```js
// x-axis
svg.append("g")
  .attr("class", "x axis")
  .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
  .call(xAxis)
  .append("text")
  .attr("class", "label")
  .attr("x", width)
  .attr("y", -6)
  .style("text-anchor", "end")
  .style("fill", "black")
  .text(xText);
```

Adding

```js
.transition()
.duration(100)
```

results in an error while appending text. I am new  to D3 and I am unable to figure out how this can be done.

Comment: Well, this is just a mess. Please **do not** keep editing your question for a different one, this is quite unfair with people that devoted time/energy for providing you an answer. If you have another question, or if you forgot to add information regarding your original goal in such a way that the edited question requires a completely different answer, post **another** question instead.

Comment: ok, I will  remember this in future. Thank you.

Comment: no worries. If you want to refactor someone else's code, post a question in which you link the code, then make clear in the question that the code is not yours (or else people will not adequate their answers to your knowledge level), explain how you want to refactor it and, finally, add all the relevant info, including what you tried and the errors you got. Remember that you can take all the time you want revising your question before posting it, but the moment you post it it's live, and people will try to answer that specific question.

Answer (score 1):

Just break your selection (and *name it*):

```
const axisGroup = svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "x axis")
      .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
      .call(xAxis);

axisGroup.append("text")
      .attr("class", "label")
      .attr("x", width)
      .attr("y", -6)
      .style("text-anchor", "end")
      .style("fill", "black")
      .text(xText);
```

Then you can do:

```
axisGroup.transition()
    //etc...
```

The explanation is that if you don't break it the whole stuff will be just a `<text>` selection.

Here is a basic demo:

```js
const scale = d3.scaleLinear([10, 290]);
const axis = d3.axisBottom(scale);
const svg = d3.select("svg");
const group = svg.append("g")
  .attr("transform", "translate(0,50)")
  .call(axis);
group.append("text")
  .attr("x", 150)
  .attr("y", 40)
  .style("fill", "black")
  .text("Foo Bar Baz");
scale.domain([0, 50]);
group.transition()
  .delay(500)
  .duration(1000)
  .call(axis)
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.min.js"></script>
<svg></svg>
```

Comment: Sir, your code has "scale.domain([0, 50]);" which causes transition to be apparent. my scale is set well ahead of call axis. Please take a look at the original code:http://bl.ocks.org/majetisiri/57da501b3182bd08d17402261c7187f7

Comment: Please don't call me *sir*. Well, that is just a *demo*, for demonstrating the solution, it's not part of the real answer... your question here was answered above that demo. That being said, use **your** code, with your scales (by the way, if you want to know, that shorthand for the range works in D3 5.8 and above).

Comment: What I am trying to say is... as the edit shows the scales are set up before svg is created.

Comment: Then you have a different question. I rolled back your edit to the original code. If you want to refactor someone else's code, which seems to be the case, please include all relevant information in the question (not this one, I mean the future ones).